# Ruby gem that allows us to handle local system's windows

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to automate the browse and upload file in my application.Ruby(2.0) that I am using does not let me handle the local system's windows. Is there any ruby gem that allows us to handle local system's windows?

Comment: You mean something like a GUI?

Comment: Give the code you have written.

Comment: I want some suggestions on how to automate this.Firstly I would like to know is it possible to handle the local system's window through automation using ruby watir web-driver. If yes,then how?

Comment: Why do you need to handle the window or the browsing? What does this prove? Why not just set the value of the form field instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watir is for automating Browsers, not Operating Systems. Each OS is going to be different, so anything that might help you automate them will also be unique.

For Windows you might see if something [like this](https://github.com/erinata/auto_click) will do what you need. (Note I've not used this project and recommend avoiding doing OS level automation if possible).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I'll try using this.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer

Comment: I tried installing auto click gem in windows 10 and windows 7,but I'm getting the following error

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'auto' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'click' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Create an issue with this info on the project's github.